# How to override Magento model in a subdirectory?

Tags: module, magento-1, extensions, overrides, model

I'm trying to override a function in `Mage_CatalogRule_Model_Rule` but I can't get it to work.

**config.xml**

```
<config>
    <global>
        <models>
            <rule>
                <rewrite>
                    <rule>Apptha_Timer_Model_CatalogRule_Model_Rule</rule>
                </rewrite>
            </rule>
        </models>
    </global>
</config>
```

**/app/code/local/Apptha/Timer/Model/CatalogRule/Model/Rule.php**

```
class Apptha_Timer_Model_CatalogRule_Model_Rule extends Mage_CatalogRule_Model_Rule {
    protected function _convertFlatToRecursive(array $data) {
        //not called
    }
}
```

What am I missing? I've been able to override controllers and blocks just fine.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
<global>
    <models>
        <catalogrule>
            <rewrite>
                <rule>Apptha_Timer_Model_CatalogRule_Model_Rule</rule>
            </rewrite>
        </catalogrule>
    </models>
</global>
```

The node of models need to be the namespace of the module. If you instantiate the rule with `Mage::getModel('catalogrule/rule')` this needs to be `catalogrule`

This namespace can be found here:

```
/app/code/core/Mage/CatalogRule/etc/config.xml
```